# pgr_dijkstra resulting dashline road

Tags: postgis, dijkstra, pgrouting

I am trying to use pgr_dijkstra on postgis pgrouting by following code as below

```
SELECT seq, node, edge, cost_len as cost, agg_cost, geom
FROM pgr_dijkstra( 'SELECT gid as id, source, target, st_length(geom, true) as cost FROM road',
ARRAY[16106,8189,4887,23235],10576, directed:=false) as pt
JOIN road rd ON pt.edge = rd.gid;
```

[image: broken road result]

The query running successfully, but when I open the data on qgis the road segment is broken up (dash line) as shown on the image. The previous step of create_topology also running successfully. What possibly wrong with the query? or is it my road data need to be fix

Comment: could you show the QGis style you are using?

Comment: It was not because I am using dash line symbol. I used simple line symbol with width 2.0 just to show the result clearly.